# Search for a value in an arraylist within a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap that uses a ID as a key, as value has an arraylist with more ID.

I need to do a search for an ArrayList ID, but without needing to know the ID of the key.

How could you do this search?

**EDITT:** I need to look for a number, inside the arraylist without knowing its hashmap key.

**Example:**
[image]
Validate if 20 exists, if true, return 3333

Comment: Can you add the code ?

Comment: What do you want to find? The item? The list it's in? The ID? What did you try?

Comment: your question includes not enough information.

Comment: Please see the edition

Comment: @Bohemian I set an example :)

Comment: Iterate on each key of the map, search if the ArrayList contains what you want, if so, return the key. If you want some code, you are going to provide some yourself. We are not here to do your homework ;)

Comment: @AxelH It is not a HomeWork, it is a personal project, Thanks for idea :)

Comment: That's the same problem, SO is not for implement your algo. Try this yourself then ask for help if you can't finish it. Here, you just gave us the problem without a beginning of solution

Comment: It’s generally considered better style (and more efficient, but I doubt that matters here) to iterate the entry set of the map. For each entry in the entry set, search the `ArrayList` you get from `getValue()`. If a match is found, get the key from the entry and return it (returning immediately will miss the case where the ID is duplicated under more than one key, though).

Comment: And for information, if this is just Integers, the ArrayList provide you the way to check if a value is present using `contains`, so this is done in 3 lines ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help @AxelH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple loop over hashmap:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer needle = 20;

    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    hm.put(1111, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    hm.get(1111).add(1);
    hm.get(1111).add(2);
    hm.get(1111).add(3);
    hm.get(1111).add(4);
    hm.get(1111).add(5);
    hm.get(1111).add(6);

    hm.put(2222, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    hm.get(2222).add(8);
    hm.get(2222).add(10);
    hm.get(2222).add(11);

    hm.put(3333, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    hm.get(3333).add(15);
    hm.get(3333).add(19);
    hm.get(3333).add(20);
    hm.get(3333).add(31);

    for (Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
        ArrayList<Integer> v = entry.getValue();
        if (v.contains(needle)){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would assume your map is of type `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>`:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
```

To search for a value, do this: (I am searching for 1 in this example)

```
for (List<Integer> value : a.values()) {
    if (value.contains(1)) { // change the 1 to whatever value you're searching
        System.out.println("Found!");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use `stream`!

```
if (a.values().stream().filter(value -> value.contains(1)).count() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Found!");
}
```

Comment: I like the stream solution (except I don’t like you giviing code away to someone who has shown no effort first — we don’t like those questions and don’t want to encourage them). If you want to use a stream and you’re required to return the key from the map, that can be done too, of course. In line with what I wrote in the brackets, I will leave it as an exercise.

Comment: Even simpler: `if (a.values().stream().anyMatch(value -> value.contains(1))) {`.

Comment: In the question he asked return the `key` when match found in the `value`. But it seems in your  `stream` solution will not do that. Could you provide that solution. I am also tying to do, but not any idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with Java 8 stream.

```
  //Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();//

  int targetVal = 31;
  Optional<Integer> val = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getValue().contains(targetVal))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .findFirst();

    System.out.println(val.isPresent() ? val.get() : null);
```